# Sorting algorithm that is calling itself on 2/3 of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I try to implement  a sorting algorithm that works as follows: *given an array of length n the algorithm should recursively call itself on the first 2/3, then on the last 2/3 and after that again on the first 2/3 of the array. On each call the algorithm should sort the current array when it is looking at two or less elements and exit. The method should take an array A and two indices as arguments.*

So the main difficulty here is to create indices that represent the 2/3 of an array. My idea was to do `x = Math.floor((i-j)/3)` such that `x` is the number of elements in the first 1/3 and in the second 1/3. So the first 2/3 can be bounded by `[i,x*2]` and the last 2/3 by `[x+1,j]`. Do you see any mistakes in this idea?

I came up with following algorithm which is not sorting correctly.So either the algorithm or the idea above are flawed. Do you see any problems?

```
var threeSort = function(A,i,j) {

  var diff = j-i;

  if (diff <= 2) {
        if (A[j] < A[i]) {
        var tmp = A[i];
        A[i] = A[j];
        A[j] = tmp;
      }
      return;
  }

  var x = Math.floor(diff/3);

  threeSort(A,i,x*2);
  threeSort(A,x+1,j);
  threeSort(A,i,x*2);
};

var arr = [3,4,1,4,2];
threeSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jyqyhxko/2/

Comment: I don't understand why you expect this logic to sort the array. But most probably you should always return in case `diff <= 2`, not only if `A[j] < A[i]`.

Comment: @Oriol correct, I moved the return out of the inner if. The error is gone, but the algorithm is not really sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var diff = j-i;
if (diff <= 2) {
```

Imagine that i = 0, j = 2. Range 0..2 contains 3 items,

Make this correction to avoid recursive sorting of two-elements piece:

```
if (diff < 2) {
```

Next issue: your x is **relative** shift. To get **absolute** index for recursive call, you can use it like

```
if (j-i < 2){
  if (A[j] < A[i]) {
    var tmp = A[i];
    A[i] = A[j];
    A[j] = tmp; 
  };
  return;
};

var d = Math.floor((j - i + 1) / 3);

threeSort(A,i,j-d);
threeSort(A,i+d,j);
threeSort(A,i,j-d);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzyk25ex/)

Comment: I cannot apply your idea to https://jsfiddle.net/jyqyhxko/2/ . I get RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: I don't know Javascript enough to control function workflow/execution order

Comment: I think the issue is not about execution order but about the index computation. You could try pseudo code.